# Content animation does not work on iPAD, iphone with chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, ios

I have a simple animation that works on Windows but does not work on iPAD or iPhone.

THis works fine when i see it through my desktop chrome browser. But on iPAD it just shows the "Default" value and animation fails to run.

Can someone let me know what am i doing wrong. Below is my style.css

```
.typinganimation::before {
    content: 'Default';
    animation: typing infinite 12s;
    -webkit-animation: typing infinite 12s;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0% {
        content: 'A';
    }
    25% {
        content: 'B';
    }
    50% {
        content: 'C';
    }
    65% {
        content: 'D';
    }
    100% {
        content: 'A';
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes typing {
    0% {
        content: 'A';
    }
    25% {
        content: 'B';
    }
    50% {
        content: 'C';
    }
    65% {
        content: 'D';
    }
    100% {
        content: 'A';
    }
}
```

Is there anything extra that needs to be done for iOS

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26352147/9863484

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS animation not working for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894052/css-animation-not-working-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: Sorry but i dont think the solutions suggested will solve my problem. In my case the content strings are themselves not being replaced which means the animation itself is not being called

Comment: Is it only not working on IOS?

Comment: @Tim567 - I checked it on my mobile device (Nokia) , windows desktop. - Where its working. Then tried on iPhone and iPAD - not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems the content tag is not supported by Safari hence not showing up on the iPAD/iPhone